# Ubuntu 14.04 configure: error: "libxml not found"

Tags: r, xml, ubuntu-14.04, xml-libxml

Trying to install the XML package as follows I get the error `configure: error: "libxml not found"`. It seems that R is picking up the libxml2 installation from Anaconda. How can I fix this?

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

> install.packages("XML")
Installing package into ‘/home/bravegag/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/XML_3.98-1.19.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1600788 bytes (1.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 MB

* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for xml2-config... /opt/dev/anaconda/2018.12/bin/xml2-config
USE_XML2 = yes
SED_EXTENDED_ARG: -E
Minor 9, Patch 8 for 2.9.8
Located parser file -I/opt/dev/anaconda/2018.12/include/libxml2 -I/opt/dev/anaconda/2018.12/include/parser.h
Checking for 1.8:  -I/opt/dev/anaconda/2018.12/include/libxml2 -I/opt/dev/anaconda/2018.12/include
Using libxml2.*
checking for gzopen in -lz... yes
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml... no
configure: error: "libxml not found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/home/bravegag/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/XML’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpannHh6/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("XML") :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

I also get this:

```
$ type xml2-config
xml2-config is /opt/dev/anaconda/2018.12/bin/xml2-config
```

but setting the config in the R environment doesn't help:

```
Sys.setenv(XML_CONFIG="/opt/dev/anaconda/2018.12/bin/xml2-config")
```

**UPDATE** I already had libxml2 installed in the system see:

```
bravegag@zeus:~$ sudo apt-get install libxml2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxml2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
bravegag@zeus:~$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Comment: How did you launch the R shell above? With `bravegag@zeus:~$` or inside an conda virtualenv session? For non-Windows distributions, consider installing R through `apt-get` and not from Anaconda. By the way, [Ubuntu 14.04](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/09/19/extended-security-maintenance-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) reaches end of life on 04-30-2019. Consider upgrading distro version.

Comment: @Parfait launched from the shell directly or also from RStudio, same result. I installed R using apt-get. I have tried upgrading to 16.x but the upgrade process fails with errors need to zoom in into that another time. For the time being it would be great getting the XML package installation right ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your system has the `libxml-dev` or `libxml2-dev` package installed.  i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

I'm unable to determine which is the right version (libxml or libxml2) for 14.04 but you'll want to make sure you have the `-dev` version installed.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error but `libxml2-dev` was already installed so that didn't help.

What did help was to install libxml through conda using

```
conda install r-xml
```

I think there is a problem with the environment variables when you install R through conda.

Comment: I agree, this works for me. I also installed R through conda. Thanks!